# Share apklib file but hide the source code Is it possible?

Tags: android, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, proguard

So I have Android library projects which are built using android-maven-plugin. This results in the generation of .apklib snapshot. This snapshot has all the java source code and resources for that android project.

I want to share this .apklib with other users but don't want to compromise on the java source code. Is this something possible? I read about using proguard to obfuscate non public code in .apklib but the problem is that when I use proguard.cfg it generates a .jar file with the obfuscated code but it also generates the .apklib file in the group id as defined in pom.xml which has all the source code in it.

My understanding is that Maven need .apklib and all source code to build the main .apk file.

So with that can we share apklib file but hide the source code in it?

Comment: did you tried the answer? is it working?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it myself. However, here is an idea

a) Compile your code into a jar

b) Put this jar as part of apklib (this way jar + resources will be delivered as part of apklib)